# Sqlite Multiple Where Clause Syntax Error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to implement an SQLite Query where I have to use a multiple 'where' clause.
My code is something like this,

```
public boolean CheckForOption1(String ans1,String ans2,String ans3,String ans4) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ANSWER1 + " = '"+ans1+"'"+", "+ ANSWER2 + " ='"+ans2+"' "+", "+ ANSWER3 + " ='"+ans3+"'"+", "+ ANSWER4 + " ='"+ans4+"' ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

And I am calling it in my Activity like this:

```
boolean isTrue = sqLiteHandler.CheckForOption1("Fixed Angle","up to 6","Up to 4000rpm","No");
    if (isTrue){
        Toast.makeText(this, "yes its true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But I am getting an Error like this:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE answer1 = 'Fixed Angle', answer2 ='up to 6' , answer3 ='Up to 4000rpm', answer4 ='No'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `,` with `AND` to separate your conditions

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ANSWER1 + " = '"+ans1+"'"+" AND "+ ANSWER2 + " ='"+ans2+"' "+" AND "+ ANSWER3 + " ='"+ans3+"'"+" AND "+ ANSWER4 + " ='"+ans4+"' ";
```

Comment: Awesome. I am not good with Databases and you guided me right. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AND` Instead of `,` in where clause.

```
public boolean CheckForOption1(String ans1,String ans2,String ans3,String ans4) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ANSWER1 + " = '"+ans1+"'"+" AND "+ ANSWER2 + " ='"+ans2+"' "+" AND "+ ANSWER3 + " = '"+ans3+"'"+" AND "+ ANSWER4 + " ='"+ans4+"' ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```